# functional derivative and dualspace

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, dual-spaces, frechet-derivative

Consider the function space $F=\{ f : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\}$ and the empirical scalarproduct:
$$
\langle f,g\rangle:=1/n\sum^n_{i=1}f(x_i)^Tg(x_i),
$$
for a a finite dataset $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^m$. The Dualspace is defined as $F^*=\{\langle d,\cdot\rangle:d\in F\}$.
The cost functional $C$
(for example:
$$C(f)=1/n\sum_{i=1}^n\|f(x_i)-f*(x_i)\|^2$$
)
only depends on the values of $f \in F$ at the data points. As a result it was said that, the (functional) derivative of the $\operatorname{cost} C$ at point $f_0 \in F$ can be viewed as an element of $F^{*}$, which we write $\left.\partial_{f} C\right|_{f_0}$, such that $\left.\partial_f C\right|_{f_0}=\langle d|_{f_0}, \cdot\rangle$ for some $d|_{f_0} \in F$.

Can someone explain why the last equation holds? Also im not familiar with the functional derivative, but according to the definition of wiki:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative
shouldn't the derivative at $f_0$ also be a function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1):

I was just reading about the NTK paper and this is my understanding to your problem.

Firstly, the (functional) derivative through definition is a functional (meaning it maps fucntions into $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Here $C$ is a functional that maps $\mathcal{F}:=\{ \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative), given any arbitary funciton $\phi(x) \in \mathcal{F}$ and the (functional) derivative $\frac{\delta C}{\delta \rho}$, we have

$$
\frac{\delta C}{\delta \rho}[\phi(x)] = \int \frac{\delta C}{\delta \rho}(x) \phi(x) dx := \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{C[\rho+\epsilon \phi] - C[\rho]}{\epsilon}
$$

This means that functional derivative is within the dual space of $\mathcal{F}$, i.e $\mathcal{F}^{*}$.

Secondly, since $\mathcal{F}$ is a linear space of mappings between $\mathbb{R}^m $ and $ \mathbb{R}^n$, and we have its innear product defined as above. One can prove that it is a Hilbert space, therefore using the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) there there exists one and only one element $d|_{f_0}$in $\mathcal{F}$ such that

$$
\partial_{f} C|_{f_0} = <d|_{f_0},\cdot>
$$